# Firehose mode in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What is it and how can it stop it cancelling my updates from Enterprise Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to editing data in large tables using Enterprise Manager. The so called Firehose mode indicates that Enterprise Manager has not fetched all rows. When you right-click a table, and then click "Return all rows," a firehose cursor is opened and only the rows that have been processed are displayed.

See also this [Microsoft Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;286199).

Comment: Thanks, the links are a bit difficult to get to from Google for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:
http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/coding-dotnet/firehose-mode-in-sql-12150